# How can a 16-sided non-self-intersecting polygon be drawn on a 4-by-4 grid?

Tags: geometry

Let there be a square 4-by-4 grid of points in the plane.

**How can a 16-sided non-self-intersecting polygon be drawn on a 4-by-4 grid
if the 
points are the vertices of the polygon?**

.

(Don't count reflections/rotations as different polygons.)

Comment: Can we draw diagonals?

Comment: Is it considered to be an intersection if the perimeter touches the same point twice, but does not cross? (For instance, it comes in from the bottom, leaves left, does something else, comes in from the top, and leave right.)

Comment: @ Passage - There must be exactly two line segments meeting at a point whenever a point is used to draw the polygon.  . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . @ Carl - Yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example it could be something like this:

> [image: 16 sided polygon]

Comment: Congratulations - you posted 2 seconds ahead of me :) .

Comment: @Lawrence Probably ascii drawing is a little bit slower ;)

Comment: Heh. I made a mistake, corrected it, then checked it again. +1 on yours, though :) .

Answer (score 7):

Please excuse the ascii art.

```
x-x x-x
| |/  |
x x x-x
 \   \
x-x x x
|  /| |
x-x x-x
```

Comment: haha, that's innovative xD